# Workflow/processbuilder - assign task to public Group or more than one user

Tags: workflow, process-builder, tasks

When there is a change on the opportunity I need to assign a task to two users. The users are in the same role as many other users. I have tried to create separate tasks however the work will only be completed by one user.

Does anyone have any experience in creating a task through workflow/process builder and assigning it to more than one user/public group.

Many thanks,

Lex

Comment: Possible duplicate of the below post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32710/can-multiple-users-be-notified-for-a-single-task

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32710/can-multiple-users-be-notified-for-a-single-task Idea Voted for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task's "Assigned To" is a lookup that can go to User or Calendar. Compare it with say Case Owner that says it can go to User or Queue. (that's your first issue, forget public groups, read about queues). Maybe you could make something happen with public calendars / calendar sharing. Haven't used them to be honest.

So the task can only ever get one owner. If you don't want duplicated tasks (and then some mass close / delete them whenever one user completes the work) not sure what else to suggest you...

How important is this work? Is it a show-stopper without which Opportunity can't proceed? Maybe you could just submit it for approval (with multiple approves set to "first come first served" or 1 approved Queue). With the setting "approver can edit the record even though it's locked" it could work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Task can be assigned to public groups, individual users or queues. For this case, create a queue and assign to the queue the 2 correspond users so that they will be able to take any action into the created task.